# XCUITest cases after typing text of more then 23 characters my email textfield start deleting from it's 23 character in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcuitest, xctestcase

I need help with XCUITests for textfield clear text
In Below code when i will try to call clearAndEnterText() method for // Wrong Password email test case it will start removing previous text from .com (Cursor starts it's backwork method beform .com letters) so from it's 23rd character it'll start deleting text. if i'll add "janki@gmail.com" email instead of "jankiyhi123456.thakar@gmail.com" this method will work properly i have checked in my textfield that my textfield don't have any min or max length. i can not set textfield.clearsOnBeginEditing = true as i wanted to edit text as well so i got stuck in this problem. Any help would be very greatful thankyou in adnvance .
#helpinghand #iosdeveloper #uitestcases #XCUITests

```
import XCTest
import UIKit

final class LoginUITests: XCTestCase {
   
    var app: XCUIApplication!
    
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
    }
    
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        app = nil
    }
   
    func testLoginScreenWithValidations() {
        app = XCUIApplication()
        
        let emailTextField = app.textFields["Email"]
        let passwordTextField = app.secureTextFields["Password"]
        let doneButtonTap = app.toolbars["Toolbar"].buttons["Done"] // Hide keyboard
        let loginButton = app.buttons["Login"]

        // Email Not Exist
        let emailInCorrect = "jankiyhi123456.thakar@gmail.com"
        let passwordCorrect = "janki@123"
        
        emailTextField.clearAndEnterText(text: emailInCorrect)
        doneButtonTap.tap()
        
        passwordTextField.clearAndEnterText(text: passwordCorrect)
        doneButtonTap.tap()
        
        loginButton.tap()
        sleep(3)
        
        // Api - Wrong Password
        let emailCorrect = "janki12345678.thakar@gmail.com"
        let passwordInCorrect = "janki@1"
        
        emailTextField.clearAndEnterText(text: emailCorrect)
        doneButtonTap.tap()
        
        passwordTextField.clearAndEnterText(text: passwordInCorrect)
        doneButtonTap.tap()
        
        loginButton.tap()
        sleep(3)
    }
 }

extension XCUIElement {
    func clearAndEnterText(text: String) {
        guard let stringValue = self.value as? String else {
            XCTFail("Tried to clear and enter text into a non string value")
            return
        }
        
        self.tap()
        
        let deleteString = String(repeating: XCUIKeyboardKey.delete.rawValue, count: stringValue.count)
        
        self.typeText(deleteString)
        self.typeText(text)
    }
    
}
```